# Counting how many values but the most common one there is in a data.frame, with R

Tags: r

Sample datas :

```
    > ind1
             Ind Gb19a Gb19b Gb24a Gb24b Gb28a Gb28b Gb11a Gb11b
    1  9-2-J1-N3   378   386   246   248   360   372   162   261
    2  9-2-J1-N3   380   386   246   248   360   372   187   261
    14 9-2-J1-N3   380   386   246   248    NA    NA    NA    NA
    15 9-2-J1-N3    NA   246   248   360   187    NA    NA    NA
    16 9-2-J1-N3   380   386   380   386   378   386   380   386
    17 9-2-J1-N3   380   386   246   248   360   372   187   261
    19 9-2-J1-N3   360   372   360   372   360   372   360   372
    20 9-2-J1-N3   187   261   187   261   162   261   187   261
    21 9-2-J1-N3   380   386   240   246   360   372   187    NA

> class(ind1)
[1] "data.frame"
```

So I need to count, for every columns, how many values but the most common one there is. Expected output would be :

Gb19a 3
Gb19b 3
Gb24a 5
ect...

I have a solution given by folks here from a previous question I asked, (thanks to them) that explicitly do calculation for every variable, but I don't think it's a workable solution for my situation.

```
 > table(ind1$Gb19a)

    187 360 378 380 
      1   1   1   5

    counts1 <- as.data.frame(table(ind1$Gb19a), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    modal_value1 <- which.max(counts1$Freq)
    (sum(counts1$Freq)-counts1$Freq[modal_value1])
    [1] 3
```

How to apply this to entire data.frame ?

As always, thanx for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just say the word !
("How to **apply** this to entire data.frame?")

```
countValsButMostFreq <- function(values){
  counts1 <- as.data.frame(table(values), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  modal_value1 <- which.max(counts1$Freq)
  return (sum(counts1$Freq)-counts1$Freq[modal_value1])
}

ind1 <- rbind.data.frame(
c('9-2-J1-N3',   378,   386,   246,   248,   360,   372,   162,   261),
c('9-2-J1-N3',   380,   386,   246,   248,   360,   372,   187,   261),
c('9-2-J1-N3',   380,   386,   246,   248,    NA,    NA,    NA,    NA),
c('9-2-J1-N3',    NA,   246,   248,   360,   187,    NA,    NA,    NA),
c('9-2-J1-N3',   380,   386,   380,   386,   378,   386,   380,   386),
c('9-2-J1-N3',   380,   386,   246,   248,   360,   372,   187,   261),
c('9-2-J1-N3',   360,   372,   360,   372,   360,   372,   360,   372),
c('9-2-J1-N3',   187,   261,   187,   261,   162,   261,   187,   261),
c('9-2-J1-N3',   380,   386,   240,   246,   360,   372,   187,    NA))
colnames(ind1) <- c('Ind', 'Gb19a', 'Gb19b', 'Gb24a', 'Gb24b', 'Gb28a', 'Gb28b', 'Gb11a', 'Gb11b')



res <- apply(X=ind1,MARGIN=2,FUN=countValsButMostFreq)
res
```

Result:

```
  Ind Gb19a Gb19b Gb24a Gb24b Gb28a Gb28b Gb11a Gb11b 
    0     3     3     5     5     3     2     3     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of doing this for `mtcars`:

```
as.data.frame(
    lapply(mtcars, 
        function(x)unname(tail(sort(table(x)), 1))
    )
)

  mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
1   2  14    3  3    3  3    2 18 19   15   10
```

---

How does this work?

Set up a function to get the frequency count for a single column:

- Use `table` to get your counts
- `Sort` the results
- Get the last value with `tail`
- Use `unname` to drop the name

Then simply pass that to `lapply` and convert the results to a `data.frame`

Comment: Mmh this returns the number of occurrences of the most frequent... you should do this: `sum(tail(sort(table(x),decreasing=T),-1))`

Comment: @digEmAll Yeah the title of this post is misleading and I think that's why Andrie did this.

Comment: @TylerRinker: yes, the title is a little misleading; I confess I used the example provided to understand what to do. Anyway, the tail-sort approach is very smart :)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the apply family.  I'd probably use sapply here but that's your choice.

```
   ind1 <- read.table(text="Ind Gb19a Gb19b Gb24a Gb24b Gb28a Gb28b Gb11a Gb11b
    1  9-2-J1-N3   378   386   246   248   360   372   162   261
    2  9-2-J1-N3   380   386   246   248   360   372   187   261
    14 9-2-J1-N3   380   386   246   248    NA    NA    NA    NA
    15 9-2-J1-N3    NA   246   248   360   187    NA    NA    NA
    16 9-2-J1-N3   380   386   380   386   378   386   380   386
    17 9-2-J1-N3   380   386   246   248   360   372   187   261
    19 9-2-J1-N3   360   372   360   372   360   372   360   372
    20 9-2-J1-N3   187   261   187   261   162   261   187   261
    21 9-2-J1-N3   380   386   240   246   360   372   187    NA", header=TRUE)

hapax <- function(x) {x <- na.omit(x); length(setdiff(unique(x), x[duplicated(x)]))}
sapply(ind1, hapax)
```

Answer (score 0):

apply(mymatrix, 2, myfunc) runs myfunc(onecolumn) on each column matrix, or data frame.

myfunc would be the code you posted to calculate the sum, except ind1$Gb19a is replaced with onecolumn.